# ATI Stream OpenCL: Problem while opening opencl kernel file in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, file-io

```
FILE *fp;
long filelen; long readlen;
char* src;
fp = fopen("OpenCLSource.cl","r");
fseek(fp,0L,SEEK_END);
filelen = ftell(fp);
rewind(fp);
src = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*(filelen+1));    
readlen = fread(src,1,filelen,fp);
src[filelen+1] = '\0';
fclose(fp);
```

I typed in this code, and I got an error that it's fopen is deprecated, I solved the problem by getting help from a forum i.e, I added _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS to the preprocessor definitions.

But, I STILL can't load the kernel file. There are "no" errors or warnings. Value of fp is ZERO
Is there any alternate method to do this??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure the file exists and in the correct location? Other than that your question has nothing to do with OpenCL or hardly any of the tags specified.

Comment: @Bart, Yes the file exist in the same project folder, I even tried giving the full path, and it didn't work. Yeah, this question is mostly related to file, sorry for that. @Ludwig I tried that, value of fp is 0 and that of fseek is also 0. The right method is given in the OpenCL SDK samples by ATI, but I can't follow it properly since I'm new to this.

Comment: Have a look to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5hh6ee9%28v=vs.80%29.aspx on fopen_s. Maybe it helps. I am not familiar with Visual Studio, but your source works on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

`fopen` is a POSIX command. For Linux the man page tells:

```
RETURN VALUE
   Upon successful completion fopen(), fdopen() and freopen() return a FILE
   pointer. Otherwise, NULL is returned and errno is set to indicate the error.
```

I think this is valid for the Windows implementation as well. You can get the the error code by checking the variable errno. A user readable string can be got with strerror:

```
char *str = strerror(errno);
printf("error: %s\n", str);
```

Hopefully, this works on Windows, too.